# Sync directory across two servers using rsync (or alternative for syncing directories)

Tags: linux, rsync, replication, copy

I have two VMs that should have identical files in this directory:

```
/var/www/owncloud/data/admin/files/
```

I initially thought that I could use rsync with cron to copy the files every two minutes:

On VM1:

```
*/2 * * * * rsync -auz --delete-after /var/www/owncloud/data/admin/files root@VM2:/var/www/owncloud/data/admin
```

On VM2

```
*/2 * * * * rsync -auz --delete-after /var/www/owncloud/data/admin/files root@VM1:/var/www/owncloud/data/admin
```

The problem I'm running into is if I upload a file to VM1, after two minutes, the cronjob on VM2 overwrites the directory on VM1, deleting the file.

The reason I am copy from VM1->VM2 and VM2->VM1 is because I have a very basic failover set up. If VM1 goes down and files are added/removed from VM2, I want those changes duplicated on VM1; and of VM1 is up and files are added/removed, I want those changes duplicated on VM2.

Is this possible to do with rsync? Is my command wrong? Is there an alternative I should use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at unison, it allows for bi directional sync: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

Comment: This looks really simple, I'll take a look. Thanks! (If it ends up working I'll let you know/accept your answer)

Comment: This seems to have worked. I can just have my primary node set to sync every 2 minutes and it will keep everything updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can prevent rsync from deleting any files from your destination.
I am not sure which flag does this.
maybe
   man rsync
should help you?

Comment: I actually would want files deleted if they were deleted from one, but not the other. This is where the issue is coming in, because I can't determine if the files were deleted, or if the file never existed.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you....you would want files to be deleted from one, and not other?....how will that help you keep your servers in sync?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use rsync - the best way would be avoid option '--delete-after'.
But if you do so, there could be situations when file will be recreated on one, or another node.
After some having practice with bi-directional sync (via [csync2](http://oss.linbit.com/csync2/paper.pdf) and this [doc](https://www.axivo.com/community/threads/lightning-fast-synch-with-csync2-and-lsyncd.121/) with some modifications to lsyncd config), I've found that best option would be some shared FS (NFS for tests, GFS, etc.)